# Show Child content type columns on list view of parent folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, content-type, list-view

We are working on a Dynamics CRM – SharePoint integration in which we would like to extend the default integration so our SharePoint site will be more accessible if the site is not accessed from CRM. By default CRM creates a docuemtn library for each record type but we would like use the Account library and create a repeating folder structure for each account. This results in the following folder structure with meta data fields:

Accounts (**Document library**)

- Account (**Folder**, AccountName, AccountNumber, Account Type)

  - Invoices (**Folder**)

    - Invoice (**File**, Invoice number, Invoice date, Invoice Type)
  - Quotes (**Folder**)

    - Quote (**File**, QuoteName, QuoteNumber, QuoteDate, QuoteType)
  - Visit Reports (**Folder**)

    - Visit Report (**File**, Subject, Visit date, Visit Type)

We have been able to create the structure by creating content types and setting the allowed child content types but are still struggling to set the list view of each parent folder to show the right columns. So when a user accesses the Invoices folder under an account folder all invoice columns should be displayed. When he opens the Quotes folder only the quote fields should appear.
Is it possible to set the default view columns of a content type to show child content type columns?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to change the columns to display in a list view based on content types.

By default, all columns attached to the content types will be available in this library. We can only decide which columns to display on separate list views.

There is a workaround if you are open for using classic experience: [Harness SharePoint Library and Folder Default Views to build more appealing solutions.](https://camerondwyer.com/2014/01/06/harness-sharepoint-default-views-at-different-navigation-hierarchy-levels-to-build-more-appealing-solutions/)

You can use the built-in **"Show this view"** option via *Edit View* > *Folders* > **In folders of content type** to decide which list view to display when user access this child content type. Please note that this feature is not supported in modern experience for the time being.